# Content Editable Div - How to wrap a matching word in span element while typing and keeping in mind the caret position

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, contenteditable

I am creating a special field of content editable where I can easily highlight or replace certain reserved texts if matched by their specific commands. It includes mentions(@), hashtags(#), and some words like "high", "medium" and "low" whose colors will be changed if matched.

For example, if the user goes typing "high" then what needs to be done is we've to encapsulate that in span tag with some styles on it and place the caret only at the end of this particular word.

The problem faced by me is about the position of the caret after replacing that word as it always sets to the end of the sentence even if I am typing somewhere in the middle.

Here is my HTML code :

```
<div id="textBox" contenteditable="true" class="c-edit-container">
</div>
```

And this is JS:

```
let containerEl = document.getElementById('textBox')

function getWordPrecedingCaret() {
    let _selection = window.getSelection();
    if (!_selection.rangeCount) return;
    let _range = _selection.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
    _range.collapse(true)
    _range.setStart(containerEl, 0);

    var words = _range.toString().split(' '),
        lastWord = words[words.length - 1];
    if (lastWord && lastWord == 'high') {
        var wordStart = _range.toString().lastIndexOf(lastWord);
        var wordEnd = wordStart + lastWord.length;

        _range.setStart(_selection.focusNode, wordStart);
        _range.setEnd(_selection.focusNode, wordEnd);
        _range.deleteContents();
        let el = document.createElement('span');
        el.style.color = 'red';
        el.contentEditable = false;
        el.innerHTML = 'high';
        _range.insertNode(el);
        _range.setStartAfter(el)
    }
}

containerEl.addEventListener('keyup', getWordPrecedingCaret);
containerEl.addEventListener('click', getWordPrecedingCaret);
```

Comment: You would need to use the `selection` API to store the caret position and restore after your wrapping. If you show some code, I would be able to suggest ways to achieve what you want. There are similar questions on SO all with problems and challenges of creating a rich text editor with a contenteditable.

Comment: @maswerdna I have added my sample code